# How to merge 2 sql queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

Table1

```
id,
table2_id
```

Table2

```
Table2
id,
param1
```

Table3

```
id, 
table1_id,
param2
```

Also I have 2 sql queries:

```
select * from Table1 g
join Table2 f on g.table2_id = f.id
where f.param1 = '111'
```

```
select * from Table1 g
join Table3 k on k.table1_id = g.id
where k.param2 = '111'
```

I want to merge these two queries into one like:

```
(select * from Table1 g
join Table2 f on g.table2_id = f.id
where f.param1 = '111')
union
(select * from Table1 g
join Table3 k on k.table1_id = g.id
where k.param2 = '111')
```

But the result of each query are not the same and I get an error. How I can merge it?

EDIT:
If I'm use the solution from comment with double join tables, i'll get the unwanted result,

For example, in first table i have this data

```
id:1  
table2_id:1
```

In the second one i have this data:

```
id:1 
param1: 111
```

In the third one I have tish data:

```
id:1  
table1_id:1  
param2:112,

id:2  
table1_id:1  
param2:113
```

And if I'm use this sql:

```
select * from Table1 g
    join Table2 f on g.table2_id = f.id
    join Table3 k on k.table1_id = g.id
where f.param1 = '111' or k.param2 = '111'
```

I'll get this result
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPSjZ.jpg)
But if I'm use the separate sql queries, I'll get the only 1 row.

Comment: Sample Data expected results:  I see the sample data, ***What's expected results?***  As far as how do you union the data: 1) Columns data type and count must be the same as does collation.  2) Align/order columns so they match in position. So I'd start off by spelling out each table.column (don't use *), when you have one missing, cast Null to the data type of a column in the other query which has a value.

Comment: **Never say “I got an error” without telling us what the error is.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Answer (score 0):

dont use select * ... becuase in your case first table contains 2 column where as third and second table contains 2 columns

so in union (there must be same number of fields and same name of field in both select query)
Thank you

```
    (select id,table2_id as fk_id from Table1 g
join Table2 f on g.table2_id = f.id
where f.param1 = '111')
union
(select id,table1_id as fk_id from Table1 g
join Table3 k on k.table1_id = g.id
where k.param2 = '111')
```

or if you need all columns then you can do like this

```
    (select id,table2_id as fk_id,param1 as param from Table1 g
join Table2 f on g.table2_id = f.id
where f.param1 = '111')
union
(select id,table1_id as fk_id,param2 as param from Table1 g
join Table3 k on k.table1_id = g.id
where k.param2 = '111')
```